# Jest giving error in React-Navigation while running UITest case in React-Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

While trying to run UI test in react native getting error from Jest. Updated the **package.json** file as well

```
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native",
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"
]},"transformIgnorePatterns": [
"node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*))"]
```

in **/jest/setup.js** just import the `jest.mock('@react-navigation/native-stack')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in package.js

///modify this code

"jest": {

"preset": "react-native",

"resetMocks": false,

"setupFiles": [

```
  "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js",

  "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
```

],

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [

  "/node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/).*/"
```

],

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [

  "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
```

],

"moduleNameMapper": {

```
  ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "babel-jest"
}}
```

Then run your test